# Proof of diagonalizable linear tranfromation

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof that the following tranformation is diagonalizable:
$T: M_{n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ defined as T(A) = $\frac{1}{2} (A-A^{T})$

For this question, I know that $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the direct sum of symmetric and antisymmetric matrices, but I don´t know how to find a base for $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. Additionally I thought I could prove it by induction, but I don´t know how.

Also I think that the following is true, but I don´t know how to prove it:

There exists a diagonalizable linear transformation $T: \mathbb{C}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2}$ with eigenvalues$\pm i$

Any help or hint is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Compute $T^2{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: But for the first question T^2 = T ! Are you referring to the first or second question ?

Comment: the first one. And what about this kind of function?

Comment: what is an endomorphism ? I hadn´t saw that in my linear algebra class :(

Comment: I edited. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

For the second question I believe the matrix
$$T = \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 \\
0 & -i \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
does the job.

For the first question look at what happens for $T^2$. It follows almost trivially from that.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you have the decomposition $$M_n(\mathbb{R})=Sym_n(\mathbb{R})\oplus Asym_n(\mathbb{R}),$$where $Sym,Asym$ is for symmetric and antisymmetric matrices, respectively. Note that $$T|_{Sym_n(\mathbb{R})}=0,\\T|_{Asym_n(\mathbb{R})}=id,$$so just choose any basis of each one of the components, and you got a basis of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ that consists of eigenvectors of $T$.